# Sort Apache SOLR search result - sentence

Tags: javascript, apache, sorting, solr

How I can sort the Apache SOLR search result by number of repeated words per sentence that I'm searching for.

For example I'm searching for word ***THIS*** and in the *first* JSON object word **THIS** appears 1 time. In the *second* 4x and in the *third* 2x.

I want search result to be sorted in this order:
***Second object*, *Third object*, *First object***

(By number of ***THIS*** in the sentences)

Can I achieve this result using just Apache SOLR or its maybe better to get the raw result from Apache SOLR and then sort it on the client side with JavaScript?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IKM1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Solr `termfreq` relevancy function: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#termfreq

```
termfreq(text,THIS)
```

You would use the result of this function in a Solr sort parameter: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/function-queries.html#FunctionQueries-SortByFunction

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection_name/select?q=*:*&sort=termfreq(text, THIS) desc
```

Comment: Works perfect for me! Thank you @christofr you are amazing!

Comment: I have one question. For example when I search for "Ananas" its looks good, because that word exist in the json data - http://prntscr.com/jwfew5 
But when I search for the for example "Bubble" I still get the result, even if that word doesn't exist in the JSON - http://prntscr.com/jwffp4 @christofr

Comment: Hi John, this is because you have replaced your query with the one in my example (q=*:*) which returns all documents. Try changing the query to something like q=text:*Bubble* to only return documents where the text field contains the term Bubble.